# Angular2, when to use bootstrap function

Tags: angular

I'm studying angular 2 and I have some questions about it.

I'm learning DI system with ng2 and I was wondering if I should put every dependency inside of the bootstrap functions at the root file of my app.

Maybe something like:

```
bootstrap(app, [Dep1,Dep2,Dep3,Dep4,...,Dep99,...DepN]);
```

Or should I split it into multiple files?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is your choice.

The first method (put everything on root), is similar to the Angular 1.x way (or how it is usually implemented in Angular 1.x).

The second one is a more modular approach and I guess it will be better over time. It is also similar to what John Papa recommends in his AngularJS style guid (ng1):

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 1):

Did you check those two page?

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/20/host-and-visibility-in-angular-2-dependency-injection.html

There is all you need about dependency injection in agular2. Especially the second link should help you to answer on your question. Generally, if you want to have some object (services or similar) which will be accessible in whole application then you suppose to put it into bootstrap arguments fe. see root router.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a dependency on bootstrap method one major result is you get to share the instance in different components. A service bootstrapped will act as a singleton, on contrast with defining the service as 'provider' for component. which will cause generating a new instance of the service